# $\det(\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} A_n)=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}(\det A_n)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

If $A$ is a $n \times n$ square matrix, $\det(\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} A_n)=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}(\det A_n)$?

I think yes, since $\det(A_n)$ is a polynomial in the entries of the matrix, so it continuous. It suffices this argument to show the claim?

Comment: Yes,it suffices! Btw,i can't see the connection of question with differential equation.

Comment: You are using $n$ both as an index and as the size of the matrix.  Is the size fixed or does the size go to infinity also?